# Rbind two dataframes, where columns are not arranged in same format?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, say df1 and df2 that I need to rbind.

DF1 looks like below:

```
a   b   c
1   11  21
2   12  22
3   13  23
```

DF2 looks like below:

```
b   a   d
14  4   31
15  5   32
16  6   33
```

a,b,c,d are column names.

I want the output as below:

```
a   b   c   d
1   11  21  31
2   12  22  32
3   13  23  33
4   14      
5   15      
6   16
```

Right now, I try

final <- rbind(df1, df2)

Can this be done in r?

Comment: `data.table::rbindlist(list(df1, df2), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)`

Comment: Your output shows "d" values when "a" is 1:3 but that should not be the cast since the second dataset (which has "d") has "a" = 4:6. Depending on your use case, you may want to do a `data.table::merge()` to merge based on some key column(s). The approach suggested by @d.b should work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
NM = unique(c(names(df1), names(df2)))
mylist = setNames(lapply(NM, function(nm) c(df1[[nm]], df2[[nm]])), NM)
data.frame(lapply(mylist, function(x) x[1:max(lengths(mylist))]))
#  a  b  c  d
#1 1 11 21 31
#2 2 12 22 32
#3 3 13 23 33
#4 4 14 NA NA
#5 5 15 NA NA
#6 6 16 NA NA
```

Also try

```
merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)
```

and

```
data.table::rbindlist(list(df1, df2), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

**DATA**

```
df1 = structure(list(a = 1:3, b = 11:13, c = 21:23), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 = structure(list(b = 14:16, a = 4:6, d = 31:33), .Names = c("b", 
"a", "d"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `smartbind()` function from `gtools` package. It can be used to combine data sets with different columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend `bind_rows` from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

It's pretty straightforward, and `dplyr` is a package with a LOT of utility, so you should be able to squeeze out more use than just this single function for any project.